# While loop in bash script until some other tasks are finished (started with nohup)?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I have a bash script, where several other programes are started with nohup (all have the same executable, but different parameters), e.g.:

```
nohup ./code --p0 &
nohup ./code --p1 &
nohup ./code --p2 &
```

Is it possible to write a while loop after the nohups calls, which terminates when all the `./code` runs are finished?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for `wait`:

```
nohup ./code --p0 &
nohup ./code --p1 &
nohup ./code --p2 &
wait    # This would wait for all currently active child processes
echo "This statement would be printed after all nohup calls are finished executing"
```